# Permissio denied after chmod and cannot boot anymore

Tags: boot, permissions

I tried to `chmod 664` a folder but unfortunately forget to include the `-R` for recursive mood. So, what happen next is I got file access denied even with a simple `ls -l` in all parts of `Ubuntu` file system. When I reboot the whole thing I cannot even get past this portion:

```
/dev/sda5: clean,  nnn/nnn files, nnn/nnn blocks
```

I got the latest version of Ubuntu which is `20.04` since this was installed more than a month ago with no problem afterwards.

I tried to boot in **safemode** using <kbd>esc</kbd> key during boot and still it will go up to the above line that I showed earlier.

Is my only recourse a reinstall at this point? Thanks.

Comment: What folder? Directories usually need execute permission for at least their owner - otherwise they are not traversable. If anything it's likely *fortunate* that you forgot the `-R`

Comment: It's one of the folders under `lib64` directory.

Comment: Well, you should be able to boot a live DVD/USB/CD, mount the filesystem, and revert your change from there

Comment: I'll try that one. I don't know the original permission though. Should I go with `775`?

Comment: ... should likely be 7**5**5 I think

Comment: Thank you. But i have a question. I don't have access to Windows OS. I have a Mac and I can make a bootable USB running on Ubuntu but it would be for Mac not my existing non-working Linux PC. Can't find one so far that you can create bootable on Mac that will run on Linux.